# The approximation ratio of approximation algorithm

Tags: approximation

I am studying the approximation  algorithm. I have a question as follows.

For an approximation algorithm for maximization problem, if I have $sol \ge \alpha opt - c$, where $c$ is a positive constant and $0 < \alpha < 1$, can i say that this algorithm is $\alpha$-apx? Why?